# Property file same key with different value in java

Tags: java, properties

I have a property file like this.

```
host=192.168.1.1
port=8060
host=192.168.1.2
port=8070
host=192.168.1.3
port=8080
host=192.168.1.4
port=8090
```

Now I want the unique url so I can pass it to other application.
**Example**

```
HostOne   : https://192.168.1.1:8060
HostTwo   : https://192.168.1.2:8070
HostThree : https://192.168.1.3:8080
HostFour  : https://192.168.1.4:8090
```

How can I get it using Java or any other library. Please help.

Thanks.

**EDITED**

How about this if I will this type of data.

```
host=192.168.1.1,8060
host=192.168.1.1,8060
host=192.168.1.1,8060
host=192.168.1.1,8060
```

Now is there any way to get this. ?

Comment: Well, you write some code that opens that text file and fetches the information from it? Where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: Is that property file a plain `.txt` file?

Comment: it is .properties file

Answer (score 4):

Basically that property file is broken. A property file is a sequence of key/value pairs which is build into a map, so it requires the keys be unique. I suspect that if you load this into a `Properties` object at the moment, you'll get just the last host/port pair.

Options:

- Make this a *real* properties file by giving unique keys, e.g.

  ```
  host.1=192.168.1.1
  port.1=8060
  host.2=192.168.1.2
  port.2=8070
  ...
  ```
- Use a different file format (e.g. JSON)
- Write your own custom parser which understands your current file format, but *don't* call it a "properties file" as that has a specific meaning to Java developers

Personally I'd probably go with JSON. For example, your file could be represented as:

```
[
    { "host": "192.168.1.1", "port": 8060 },
    { "host": "192.168.1.2", "port": 8070 },
    { "host": "192.168.1.3", "port": 8080 },
    { "host": "192.168.1.4", "port": 8090 }
]
```

Comment: But it is a property file because it also has other properties which has unique keys and values.

Comment: @Harshil: Well you didn't tell us about that... in that case you could either convert the whole thing to JSON or edit the host/port properties to be unique as per option 1.

Comment: sorry for less info. but is there option based on your experience.

Comment: Edited the question can you please check

Comment: @Harshil: That doesn't change the fundamental problem: **your properties file isn't a sensible one**. Properties files are designed to have unique keys. Your files don't. The three options I've outlined are still all the reasonable ones.